# Folders in Jenkins not showing last success , last failure , last duration in dashboard

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I created folder in jenkins **Tests** to store associated tests under that folder . Then , I created jobs under the folder .Now in dashboard , I am not able to see overall status of jobs under that folder .Please refer screenshot:

[image: Tests Status Showing NA]

How to show overall status of jobs as combine for folder in dashboard? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can't. There is no universally agreed way on how to aggregate, so no.

Comment: @Ian W - What's the best practice here if I want to get the overall status of jobs ,if not in Folders .

Comment: IDK; maybe try [Dashboard View plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/dashboard-view/) or similar.